# Creating a flash drag and drop Jewellery game?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to design a child's bracelet game, where they can drag and drop beads onto a string (circle)
but I'm having trouble snapping the object onto my ellipse (circle),
Currently the ball (bead) is stuck rotating around the ellipse,
but I need it and multiples to be dragged from the bottom of the screen and then be able to snap to the ellipse once its closer,
basically so that the child can choose a bead and drag it onto a string, to create their very own bracelet,

Could you help me at all with this? The code below is what I have so far,
any help or step in the right direction would be great thank you! :)

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var rX:Number = 150;
var rY:Number = 150;
var numItems:Number = 12;
var zeroSector:Object = sector(0, rX, rY);

function sector(degree:Number, radiusX:Number, radiusY:Number):Object {
    // coordinates of a point on ellipse
    var xpos:Number = radiusX * Math.cos(degree * Math.PI / 180);
    var ypos:Number = radiusY * Math.sin(degree * Math.PI / 180);

    // find the angle that has the Y-coords of the mouse position, solve for angle somehow...
    return {x:xpos, y:ypos};
}


function objPosition():void { // detecting coordinates of a clip
        var ratio:Number = rX / rY;

        var anAngle = Math.atan2(mouseX - myEllipse.x, mouseY - myEllipse.y );
           var deg:Number = 90-(Math.atan2(Math.sin(anAngle), Math.cos(anAngle) * ratio)) * (180 /  Math.PI);

        var _sector:Object = sector(deg, rX, rY);
        trace(_sector.x)
        bntMc.x = _sector.x;
        bntMc.y = _sector.y;

}

// draw ellipse
var myEllipse:Sprite = new Sprite();
myEllipse.x = 275;
myEllipse.y = 200;
myEllipse.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0xAAAAAA);
myEllipse.graphics.moveTo(zeroSector.x, zeroSector.y);

for (var d:int = 0; d <= 360; d += 5) {
    var _sector:Object = sector(d, rX, rY);
    myEllipse.graphics.lineTo(_sector.x, _sector.y);
}


addChild(myEllipse);

// my object
var bntMc:Sprite = new Sprite();
bntMc.graphics.lineStyle(50, 0x002277, 100);
bntMc.graphics.lineTo(0, 1);
bntMc.x = zeroSector.x;
bntMc.y = zeroSector.y;
bntMc.buttonMode = true;
myEllipse.addChild(bntMc);


bntMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, doMouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseOut);

function doMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void  {
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, doMouseMove);       
};

function  doMouseOut (event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, doMouseMove);
 };

 function doMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
     objPosition();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
var rX:Number = 150; 
var rY:Number = 150; 
var numItems:Number = 12; 
var zeroSector:Object = sector(0, rX, rY); 

function sector(degree:Number, radiusX:Number, radiusY:Number):Object { 
    // coordinates of a point on ellipse 
    var xpos:Number = radiusX * Math.cos(degree * Math.PI / 180); 
    var ypos:Number = radiusY * Math.sin(degree * Math.PI / 180); 

    // find the angle that has the Y-coords of the mouse position, solve for angle somehow... 
    return {x:xpos, y:ypos}; 
} 


function objPosition():void { // detecting coordinates of a clip 
        var ratio:Number = rX / rY; 

        var anAngle = Math.atan2(mouseX - myEllipse.x, mouseY - myEllipse.y ); 
           var deg:Number = 90-(Math.atan2(Math.sin(anAngle), Math.cos(anAngle) * ratio)) * (180 /  Math.PI); 

        var _sector:Object = sector(deg, rX, rY); 
        trace(_sector.x) 
        bntMc.x = _sector.x; 
        bntMc.y = _sector.y; 

} 

// draw ellipse 
var myEllipse:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
myEllipse.x = 275; 
myEllipse.y = 200; 
myEllipse.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0xAAAAAA); 
myEllipse.graphics.moveTo(zeroSector.x, zeroSector.y); 

for (var d:int = 0; d <= 360; d += 5) { 
    var _sector:Object = sector(d, rX, rY); 
    myEllipse.graphics.lineTo(_sector.x, _sector.y); 
} 


addChild(myEllipse); 

// my object 
var bntMc:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
bntMc.graphics.lineStyle(50, 0x002277, 100); 
bntMc.graphics.lineTo(0, 1); 
bntMc.x = zeroSector.x; 
bntMc.y = zeroSector.y; 
bntMc.buttonMode = true; 
myEllipse.addChild(bntMc); 


bntMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, doMouseDown); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, doMouseOut); 

function doMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void  { 
     //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, doMouseMove);
     bntMc.startDrag();
}; 

function  doMouseOut (event:MouseEvent):void { 
    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, doMouseMove); 
    bntMc.stopDrag();
    objPosition();
 }; 

 function doMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void { 
     objPosition();
 }
```

Comment: What you may want to do is add a condition where it would only snap if it was close enough to the circomfrence of the circle.

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for! would I put that in my function objPosition() ? or on one of the event listener functions?

Comment: I think it would go best in objPosition().